# Ajax call into httpstatusready=4 doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax - which works fine - to pass on the value. But when I add the HTTP code, there is no action. Using simple HTTP to show different `div` values based on `http.readystatus`. Is this the right format? If not, what is?

```
if (colorToCheck == gup("Player1")) {
    document.getElementById('win').innerHTML = player1 + " wins";
    redScore += 1;

    //Browser Support Code
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 3 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("save").innerHTML = "saving";
    } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //ajax call
        var dataString = 'winner=' + player1 + '&player1=' + player1 + '&player2=' + player2 + '&matchNum=' + matchNum;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "red.php",
            data:dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('.result13').html(response);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you mixing the two ways of making an Ajax call? Are you sure the status is 200?

Comment: @epascarello  ya the page is fine.. I still haven't got hold of ajax well..sorry am new in this..thanks for replyin..And what can be a better format??My http must work on ajax function call

Comment: @epascarello SO can I put this http status call inside ajax success function..

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I want to include httpreadystatus inside ajax? how do I do that..That is when ajax call is done, I need saving.. and then status code=4 saved..any simpler way?

Comment: Just forget XMLHTTPRequest, and use jQuery.AJAX

Answer (score 2):

The structure of a [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) AJAX call is:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","path/to/file.php"); // or "POST" if needed
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 3) document.getElementById('save').innerHTML = "saving";
    if( this.readyState == 4) {
        if( this.status != 200) alert("ERROR: Server returned "+this.status+" "+this.statusText);
        else {
            // do something
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.send(data); // data is whatever POST data you want. Leave out if using GET.
```

Comment: Vanilla JS is so popular that it comes pre-installed. Even jQuery uses it. ;)

Comment: That goes there I put the `data` in the code above the last line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel bad for making a joke at your expense... "Vanilla JS" is just a term used to mean plain, normal JavaScript, without any frameworks like jQuery or Underscore or any of those other ones. The website I linked is a joke, pretending that Vanilla JS is some kind of extension that's so magical it's already in your browser, and then goes on to demonstrate how much faster it is to use plan JavaScript than any framework.

Comment: That's fine, just define your variable at any time before calling `xmlhttp.send`, then when you call `xmlhttp.send` pass the variable where I wrote `data`. Also, make sure you use `"POST"` in the `xmlhttp.open` call, otherwise the server won't see it!